# Linked Pie Chart using Flot 0.7 returns "undefined" links

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to create a Flot pie chart with a link in each wedge, so I can direct users to the appropriate details page on clicking.

There is already a similar post at [With flot, how can I create a linked pie chart that takes you to other web pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633728/with-flot-how-can-i-create-a-linked-pie-chart-that-takes-you-to-other-web-pages). I tried the answer on that page with with Flot 0.7 to obtain pie wedges with hyperlinked labels. However, series.URL returns "undefined" in the labelFormatter function. How do I resolve this issue?

***On a side note***: Its my first time posting here. I tried to ask this obviously related question at the link above so I don't create a new question for the same issue. However, it was deleted by the moderator. Wouldn't it have helped other users reading that post who suffered from the same issue to find a resolution? Not complaining, just trying to understand the rationale (have read the FAQs/Guidelines for asking questions..) behind the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the code in your linked question, they get quite close to what you want.  The problem (which trips up many people) is that the item in the `plotclick` function is not the same as the series object in your raw data.  What you can do though, is refer back to your raw data using `item.seriesIndex` in `plotclick`:

```
//setup options
//setup data
var data = [
    {
    label: "Serie1",
    data: 10,
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com"},
...
];
//call plot
//setup plotclick
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
   alert(data[item.seriesIndex].url);
});
```

I don't have it following the link, but that should be easy for you to do.

Here is some sample code in full:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/pq4Q4/

***Side note answer**:  Generally they would prefer you ask a new question instead of piling into an old question with new sub-questions.  Especially in an "answered" question (I put answered in quotes because it doesn't seem that they came to a full answer, so I can see your confusion).*